# Pages or posts for reference site

Tags: seo, site-structure

I have a suburban farm website that I made using wordpress. It is really just for fun but I want to build it with best practise in mind in case I ever want to do more with it. To this point I have been writing 'how to' and 'update' articles which are both fine as posts. I have also been writing keeping and growing guides as posts but really, this content is timeless. Before I get too far down the rabbit hole should I make this kind of content as pages? The fear is that eventually I could have hundreds of these pages, is that a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 things here:

**1.SEO:**

There is absolutely no issue in terms of ranking when it comes WP pages vs post. As long as you got rich content either should be fine.

**2.Website Structure:**

Pages vs Post could come under your website planning and future consideration. For general understanding, pages are generally for website page and posts are for the blog.

**Note:** Also, it's good to have fewer pages with rich and good length content instead of having 100s of small pages.

Answer (score 4):

> Before I get too far down the rabbit hole should I make this kind of content as pages?

Doesn't really matter as long as you remain consistent with it.  Personally, I would make this content into a custom post type and that would allow for custom taxonomies to better handle navigation and SEO issues, but this isn't necessary.

> The fear is that eventually I could have hundreds of these pages, is that a problem?

Nah. Again, as long as you are consistent about which content container you use, there's no benefit nor penalty to using posts over pages.

Answer (score 1):

Articles/posts with links to always reputable University Agriculture resources can't hurt. Try Google search [site:.edu filetype:pdf etc terms etc] for key resource docs and work from there to direct traffic/integrate with invites/orders.   In addition, several market farmers/gardeners I've spoken with report earnings near or better from farm holiday/edu-tainment/activity/tourism events than actual field produce sales - which have advantage of dates/times and so always fresh upcoming content. With CMS platforms  custom content forms and filters/list can make events calanders easy.